# How can I open an application when a secondary monitor is connected?

Tags: macos, display

I use [SecondBar](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=79) to add a menu bar to an external display. I've added it to my login items, but I don't want it to open when there isn't an external display. How do I open SecondBar when a secondary monitor is connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the free/open source app [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/).

You can trigger different actions based on context-sensitive rules, including launching an app in response to connecting a display.

Comment: Great answer and great app!! I love it!! Just as a note, it can be a bit confusing, so read the help pages. They *do* actually help. =D

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of automatically doing it with out modifying the operating system, as the display is managed as a core process. The best is just to put a shortcut on your desktop and open it when you are plugging in a display

Comment: Well, it obviously isn't that hard to "modify the operating system" as you say, because ControlPlane works just fine.